# Assess bearing force ratings

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, stresses, bearings

Suppose that a ball bearing has axial and radial force ratings of 300N. If the bearing is to hold a 1m long shaft in its bore with a 1kg load on the end of the shaft, will the ratings be exceeded? The torque due to gravity is 10Nm, but how should torque be compared to the bearing's force ratings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decompose the moment load into radial and axial loads on the bearing. 

Are the bearing ratings for combined or individual loads?

Comment: @jko It's not quite clear if the ratings are for combined or individual loads. I'm guessing it's individual loads: http://www.nsk.com/common/data/ctrgPdf/e1102m.pdf

Comment: Which bearing in particular? That's a link to whole catalogue

Comment: @jko Oh, of course. I'm looking at something like MF 128 which has a rating of 545N/274N.

Comment: Shaft diameter? 10mm? that will flex under its own mass... 1m diameter, then more than one bearing needed. Show some design... a 2m long shaft supported at two points leaving a 1m shaft extending?

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-meter cantilever shaft supported by a single ball bearing is not going to work regardless of the bearing's specs.
All cantilever shafts and rods when spinning go into an increasingly unbalanced whiplash motion bending the shaft like a quadratic graph rotating about the X-axis with the centripetal force constantly increasing, leading to breaking the shaft or the ball bearing.

it is recommended to use at least two ball bearings set apart at least 1 meter and dynamic frequency of the system be designed such that there is no resonance between the natural frequency of the system and frequency of the rotation or their harmonics.

Comment: Unless it’s rotating *very* slowly